# Using Office 2016 to call getUserIdentityTokenAsync fails

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are developing an Outlook Add-in that calls `getUserIdentityTokenAsync()`.

Sometimes for some users it returns an error, but at the same time other users get the token.

We are using Office 2016, version 1710 (build 8613.1000 Click-to-Run) which is an Office Insider build, but also get the error on Office 2016 Current Channel.

Comment: When you say "sometimes for some users" are you saying that for `someuser@domain` it _occasionally_ works  or are you saying that it always works for some users and always fails for others?

Comment: I actually mean that it usually work but occasionally _different_ users fail to get the token.

Comment: Do you have error you are getting? It would be great if you can share the result you are getting when the API fails. (something like JSON.stringify(result) on failures)

Comment: We are getting this error: _"Status" = "failed", Error = {message: "An internal error has occurred", name: "Internal Error"}_

Comment: Can you see a network trace of the service method failing? Which version of Exchange are you using?

Comment: The add-in is running on Outlook App (2016 and 2013) as well as on Outlook web app - both against Office 365 (Exchange Online).

We are trying to get the network trace, as it is a bit elusive...
Restarting Outlook 2016 or refreshing the Outlook web app, sometimes resolve this issue.

Comment: We have added an extra parameter in the asyncResult object called diagnostic, for token calls, that should provide you with some more information about the failure. This should be available in clients with version > 16.0.10224.10000. Could you take a look at that and see if that helps.